# Element height does not change after updating innerHTML with XML HttpRequest

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

How should solve the following problem?

The div content changes but height does not change after updating innerHTML by XMLHttpRequest.

This is the main file:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function loadpage() 
    {   
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
        {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) 
            {
                document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        }

        xhttp.open("GET", "page.html", true);
        xhttp.send();

        document.title = document.getElementById("mydiv").clientHeight;
    }

</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="mydiv" onclick="loadpage()">hello</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the file page.html

```
<html>
<body>
1<br>
2<br>
3<br>
4<br>
5<br>
6<br>
7<br>
8<br>
9<br>
10<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `document.title = document.getElementById("mydiv").clientHeight;` does not magically keep running. It only runs when you execute it. If you want it to update, you need to run it again....

Comment: @epascarello what should be run/executed?

Comment: The line that is in the comment.... That line does not keep running. You need to set it.

Comment: That line is not my question, but why the mydiv's height does not change and how to fix it.

Comment: @epascarello Anyway, how to run it?

Comment: Put the line after the innerHTML is set?

Comment: @epascarello I don't know why, but it works! Thanks a lot! It seems that the commands "xhttp.open = ..."  and "xhttp.send = ...", and then "document.title = ..." run before the page.html loads completely.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron

Answer (score 0):

After using ".innerHTML" you may have to force-reset the height like this:

```
document.getElementById("mydiv").style.height = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the `fit-content` value to `height` property on "mydiv".

```
#mydiv {
height: fit-content;
}
```